# Error in creating array with variable name that I'm reading from file in Java

Tags: java

There are few variable in particular file. I want to read this file and create a `BitVecExpr[]` for each of this variable.

Eg: There are 3 variable G5,G6 and G7 in file(while reading from file G5 and all other variable are `string`). I want to create a 3 `BitVecExpr` array with name as G5, G6 and G7.

```
BitVecExpr[] G5 = new BitVecExpr[5];
```

Presently, I'm trying to read file and store all variable in `Arraylist`. Then using array list, I'm trying to declare `BitVecExpr`.

```
for(int i =0; i < reg.size(); i++){
BitVecExpr[] reg.get(i) = new BitVecExpr[5];
}
```

Comment: So what is your question, or your error?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "variable", "declare", "string"? An what is the reason for BitVecExpr being an array?

Comment: You can't use an expression as a variable name. Use a `Map<String, BitVecExpr[]>`.

Comment: @fdreger file  module(){  reg G5;   reg G6;   reg G7;  } when i read this file i get G5, G6 and G7 as output which are of type String. All this output i have to declare as BitVecExpr[] which is datatype of tool which i am using.

Comment: @KevinEsche I am getting error in line BitVecExpr[] reg.get(i) = new BitVecExpr[5];       ERROR: expected ; instead of "." reg.get(i)

Comment: @JBNizet i will try the Map thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to write a program which might match your requirement:

I was unable to declare Bit Vector Array as a datatype so I created example with int array as data type.

Hope this will help you.

```
public class Ajit {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add("G5");
        temp.add("G6");
        temp.add("G7");

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(temp.get(i));
        }

        Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            map.put(temp.get(i), new int[5]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(map.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read the content of your file in Array List of as string and then using hash map u can assign each of the value of array list to an int array

Comment: Tushar your code helped me. Please review my code and suggest if there are any better way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < reg_net.size(); i++){
    BitVecExpr[] temp = new BitVecExpr[count];
    reg_net1.add(temp);
    map.put(reg_net.get(i), i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < reg_net1.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < count; j++){
        reg_net1.get(i)[j] = ctx.mkBVConst("temp"+ Integer.toString(i) +"["+ Integer.toString(j) + "]",1);
    }
    }
```

In first for loop i am declaring BitVecExpr and in second for loop i am intializing it..

for below verilog file.
    reg a;
    reg b;
    reg c;
    c = a & b;

parse will give me:
    Arraylist String reg_net /// which will contain 'a','b','c'
    In 1st for loop i will create corresponding ArrayList BitVecExpr reg_net1 of same size as reg_net.
    In 2nd for loop i will intialize them as temp0, temp1, temp2

Then when i will read: c = a & b;
i will get use reg_net1.get(reg_net.indexOf("c")); // which will give me c.
    reg_net1.get(reg_net.indexOf("c"))[0] = reg_net1.get(reg_net.indexOf("a"))[0] & reg_net1.get(reg_net.indexOf("b"))[0];